# Progress of SCP in powershell (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, scp, file-transfer

I've got a script written in powershell that uses scp to transfer a file from a remote system to a local one.

```
$results = & scp -v -T "user@host:"$remote_directory" "$local_directory" 2>&1

Write-Progress -Activity "SCP file transfer" -PercentComplete 0
```

This seems to give me connection information stored in $results rather than information related to the progress of the file being transferred.  I read somewhere that on Linux, using the script command can bypass the omission of the progress, but I don't know how to accomplish this on Windows, as I don't have the "script" command.
I would also like to continue using scp, not rsync or anything.

Even while iterating the $results, the information I'm looking for is nowhere to be found.
Any help is highly appreciated.  Let me know if any further information is required.

I have tried numerous iterations of running scp, and updating -PercentComplete using many different variables derived from the results.
I was expecting to be able to update -PercentComplete accordingly to inform the user of the progress of the file being transferred.

Comment: Is that Powershell codeblock your complete code, or is there more?

Comment: There was more, but since it wasn't working, I erased the irrelevant code.  There are variable declarations at the top of the code for user, host, remote directory, and local directory, however.  
The code below the block you see was a foreach-object loop iterating through the $results variable, but since it yielded irrelevant information, I erased it.  As a side note, the scp command is transferring the file correctly, I'm simply trying to display the progress of that transfer.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The reason I was asking - since you're transferring the file, the progress should be checked constantly, and I was under the impression that you were not doing that. Please, take a look at [this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress#powershell) - the `Write-Progress` use is at the very bottom. Perhaps you could make some use of it.

Comment: It looks like implementing this will require some third party download, I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH
 Set-SCPItem -Path "$localPath" -Destination $destPathParent -NewName $destFolder -ComputerName $server -KeyFile $KeyFile -Credential $cred -AcceptKey -Force
```

You need to convert the key to openssh(if a key is used, "-credential" is needed to pass the username).
The progress bar is implemented in the module.
example:

```
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
$user,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
$server,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
$KeyFile,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
$localPath,
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
$destPath,
$backupPath

)

$Root = $PSScriptRoot





if (!($backupPath)) {$backupPath = "$PSScriptRoot\backup"}
#"Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH"

function installModule($module){

Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "Install-Module -Name $module -force" -Verb RunAs -Wait

}



Function pause ($message)
{
# Check if running Powershell ISE
if ($psISE)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
( $FrmMain = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' ).TopMost = $True
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($FrmMain,"$message")
}
else
{
Write-Host "$message" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$x = $host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
}

    

function sshShort ($sshCommand,$server,$cred,$keyfile){

$SSHsesion = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $server -KeyFile $KeyFile -Credential $cred -AcceptKey
Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $SSHsesion -Command $sshCommand -TimeOut 600
$SSHsesion | Remove-SSHSession | Out-Null
}


function sshShortWithCheck ($sshCommand,$server,$cred,$keyfile){

$console = sshShort $sshCommand $server $cred $keyfile
if ($console.ExitStatus -ne 0){

write-host "Return code $sshCommand $server not 0, $console.output, script execution terminated "

pause "Return code $sshCommand $server not 0, $console.output, script execution terminated"

exit $console.ExitStatus
}
$console
}



function checkLocalPath($localPath) {

$CheckPath = Test-Path -Path $localPath -PathType Container

if (!($CheckPath)){

$message = "The local path is not a directory, the script is shutting down"
write-host $message -ForegroundColor red
pause $message
exit 2
}
$CheckPath

}

function checkDestPath($destPath){

$destPathMassiv = $destPath -split "/"

$check = ($destPathMassiv -ge 2) -or ($destPath -eq "/")
if ($check){

write-host "The destination path cannot be empty or equal to /" -ForegroundColor red
exit 2
}
$check
}

function copyFolder ($server,$cred,$keyfile,$localPath,$destPath,$backupPath){

$localPath = Split-Path $(gci $localPath).FullName[0] -Parent
$localPath
$destFolder = Split-Path $destPath -Leaf
$destPathParent = $(Split-Path $destPath -Parent) -replace "\\","/"
$moveFullPath = "\tmp\" + "$destFolder" + "_old"

$ChecklocalPath = checkLocalPath $localPath
$checkDestPath = checkDestPath $destPath

backupDestFolder $server $cred $keyfile $localPath $destPath $backupPath

$moveDestPath = sshShort "mv -f $destPath $moveFullPath" $server $cred $keyfile
$moveDestPath
$moveDestPath.output


$console = sshShort "ls $destPath" $server $cred $keyfile

if (($console.ExitStatus -ne 0) -and ($ChecklocalPath)) {

$console = sshShort "mkdir $destPath" $server $cred $keyfile
write-host "Creating the $destPath directory" -ForegroundColor Green
}

$ConsoleScp = Set-SCPItem -Path "$localPath" -Destination $destPathParent -NewName $destFolder -ComputerName $server -KeyFile $KeyFile -Credential $cred -AcceptKey -Force
$ConsoleScp
}

function backupDestFolder($server,$cred,$keyfile,$localPath,$destPath,$backupPath){
if (!(Test-Path $backupPath)){New-Item -Path $backupPath -ItemType Directory}

$destFolder = Split-Path $destPath -Leaf
$destPathParent = $(Split-Path $destPath -Parent) -replace "\\","/"
$data = get-date -Format dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm

$console = sshShort "ls $destPath" $server $cred $keyfile
$ChecklocalPath = checkLocalPath $localPath

if (($console.ExitStatus -eq 0) -and ($ChecklocalPath)) {
try{
$ConsoleScp = Get-SCPItem -Path $destPath -Destination $backupPath -PathType Directory -ComputerName $server -KeyFile $KeyFile -Credential $cred -AcceptKey -Force
$temp = Compress-Archive -Path $("$backupPath\" + "$destFolder") -DestinationPath $("$backupPath\" + "$destFolder" + "_" +"$data.zip")
Remove-Item $("$backupPath\" + "$destFolder") -Force -Recurse
write-host "Backup of $destPath to $backupPath has been performed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch {
pause "The $destPath backup was not executed with the error $error[0], the script execution was terminated"
write-host "Backup $destPath was not executed with error $error[0], script execution terminated" -ForegroundColor Red
exit 2
}
}
else {
write-host "The $destPath directory is missing, no backup was made" -ForegroundColor Yellow
pause "The $destPath directory is missing, the backup has not been made, the script will continue to work"
}

}

if (!(Get-Module -Name Posh-SSH)){

$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"
installModule Posh-SSH
#Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -Force
}

#$localPath = "$root\test"
#$destPath = "/tmp/test"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "empty" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pwd

try {
copyFolder $server $cred $keyfile $localPath $destPath $backupPath
}
catch{
write-host $Error[0] -ForegroundColor red
exit 1
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand any of this.  You have two different code-blocks, one seemingly installing something, the other looks like it's using ssh to transfer a folder, rather than scp to transfer a file securely.  I'm not transferring folders, I'm transferring one large file.  I do appreciate this, but I need some help understanding, and possibly reforming this for single-files, instead of folders.

The arguments I'm allowed to pass are:
$1 (remotedirectory), $2 (user), $3 (hostname), $4 (filename), $5 (localdirectory), $6 (filesize - may be removed if not needed), $7 (port).

Comment: the script was given as an example. It was made to solve a specific problem. You just need to install Posh-SH, this module includes SSH and SCP.

Comment: Set-SCPItem -Path "$localPath" -Destination $destPath - this command can also work with files. My code is redundant because the directory was copied entirely to the directory that is specified. But I had to explicitly specify the destination. Previously, this module had different commands for copying files and folders, now the same command.

Comment: I got get-scpitem working, but no progress is displayed.  I have tried many different ways to get the progress to display using get-scpitem, but it's not giving me any progress information related to file transfer, or anything even remotely different from the regular scp command.

Comment: @Verify added screenshots. There is another way through c#, through creating com objects with winscp https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell.